# Is it possible to have `dput` return source code that would run outside of the enclosing environment?

Tags: r, closures, r-environment

Suppose I have a closure `add_y(y)` which returns a function that adds `y` to its input.

```
add_y <- function(y) {
  function(x) {
    x + y
  }
}
add_4 <- add_y(4)
```

So the value of `add_4` is a function that adds 4 to its input. This works. I would like to be use `dput` to show the definition of `add_4` as

```
function(x) {
  x + 4
}
```

but this is not what dput returns.

```
add_y <- function(y) {
  function(x) {
    x + y
  }
}
add_4 <- add_y(4)
dput(add_4)
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     x + y
#> }
```

Is there a way to obtain source code that would run outside of the enclosing environment?

Comment: Why don't you capture the `formals` and `args` within the `local` environment?

Comment: A closure always includes an environment. `dput` gives you the function but not the environment. `y` is stored in the environment. If you want good advice, you should explain why you need this. Why `dput` instead of serializing the closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you control add_y then a workaround would be either to inject the value of y right into the body of the inner function or else inject it into the formal argument list.  That eliminates the use of environments so the problem no longer exists.  This involves naming the anonymous inner function and only one extra line to perform the injection plus one line to return the result.

```
# 1. inject into body
add_y2 <- function(y) {
  inner <- function(x) {
    x + y
  }
  body(inner) <- do.call("substitute", list(body(inner)))
  inner
}
# test
add_4 <- add_y2(4)
dput(add_4)
## function (x) 
## {
##     x + 4
## }

# 2. inject into formal arguments
add_y3 <- function(y) {
  inner <- function(x) {
    x + y
  }
  formals(inner)$y <- y
  inner
}
# test
add_4 <- add_y3(4)
dput(add_4)
## function (x, y = 4) 
## {
##     x + y
## }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to change `add_y`. Shouldn't `body(add_4) <- do.call(substitute, list(body(add_4), environment(add_4)))` work?

Comment: That's a good idea if you don't control the function.

Comment: this works perfectly, but I am a little bit fuzzy on why! I think I need a better understanding of what "substitute" does... any advice on where I can read up on this?

Comment: `help(substitute)` would be the main authoritative source.  `substitute` replaces each variable found in the expression passed to it with its value for variables in the environment specified as the second argument and if not specified, as here, it uses the current environment.

Comment: with respect to the authors, I found this comment significantly more readable and easy to understand than what I found in `help(substitute)`! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

This can work but it involves changing the contents of `add_y`.

```r
library(rlang)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

add_y <- function(y) {
  fn <- expr(function(x) {
    x+!!y
  })
  fn <- deparse(fn) %>% str_c(collapse = "")
  fn <- eval(parse(text = fn))
}

add_4 <- add_y(4)

dput(add_4)
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     x + 4
#> }
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a `dput` replacement that generated code that creates a function like `add_4`, but it wouldn't deparse the way you want:

```r
dput_with_env <- function(f) {
  fn <- deparse(f, control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
                               "niceNames", "showAttributes"))
  env <- as.list(environment(f))
  cat("local({ f =\n")
  cat(fn, sep = "\n")
  cat("\nenvironment(f) <- list2env(\n")
  dput(env)
  cat(")\nf})")
}

add_y <- function(y) {
  function(x) {
    x + y
  }
}
add_4 <- add_y(4)

dput_with_env(add_4)
#> local({ f =
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     x + y
#> }
#> 
#> environment(f) <- list2env(
#> list(y = 4)
#> )
#> f})
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This assumes that the environment of `add_4` is quite simple, so the parent of its environment can be the environment in place when you evaluate the code.    We can try it out:

```r
newfn <- local({ f =
function (x) 
{
   x + y
}
environment(f) <- list2env(
list(y = 4)
)
f})

newfn
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>    x + y
#> }
#> <environment: 0x7f9a1b5e2318>
newfn(1)
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not with a `dput()`, no. The `dput()` function will not create text representations of environments.

If you want to save the function, you could do

```
save(add_4, file="add4.Rdata")
```

and then in another R session

```
load("add4.Rdata")
```

That will capture all the enclosed values and your function will behave as it did before